# How to assign a value returned by jQuery AJAX call to a class variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

The AJAX call returns data but how do I assign it to a class variable so that I can use it in another method? Here's my code(this is reactjs component):

```
import React from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import ListPotions from './list_potions';

export default class Potions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {potions: []};
        this.fetchPotions = this.fetchPotions.bind(this);
        this.objToStrMap = this.objToStrMap.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPotions();
    }

    fetchPotions() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.props.endPoint,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": btoa('mixOfRandomPotions')
            },
            success: function(data) {
                let potions = this.objToStrMap(data);
                this.setState({ potions });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.endPoint, status,        
                err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    objToStrMap(obj) {
        let strMap = new Map();
        for (let k of Object.keys(obj)) {
            strMap.set(k, obj[k]);
        }
        return strMap;
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.potions);
        return (
            <div className="{this.props.className}">
                <ul>
                    {this.state.potions.map((potion) => <ListPotions key="{potion.id}" potion={potion} /> )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    } 
}
```

As you can see I'm assigning it to `this.potions` but in `render()` method, the list is empty.

Comment: are you sure data is being fetched correctly?

Comment: You have to use the `state` on react components.

Comment: @Matías I tried to output it in the console multiple times, the `data` contains the fetched value.

Comment: then you should use `setState` to notify react that your component's prop are updated and it needs to be re-rendered

Comment: @Matias, I update the code to use setState, id does not work still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.potions` is probably updated, but your component is not being re-rendered with the new data. In React, you can use `state` and `setState` to easily update the internal data of a component. Here's your code (simplified):

```js
class Potions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { potions: [] };
    this.fetchPotions = this.fetchPotions.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPotions();
}

fetchPotions() {
    // not a network request, I just set some sample data. your request would go here.
    const potions = [{ id: 1, name: 'first' }, { id: 2, name: 'second' }];
    // instead of overwriting a variable (e.g. this.potions), we update the state
    // put this into your network request callback!
    this.setState({ potions });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.potions);
    return (
        <div className="{this.props.className}">
            <ul>
                {this.state.potions.map((potion) => <li key={potion.id}>{potion.name}</li> )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Potions/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: It does not work. I updated my code above to apply your solution. No luck.

Comment: Are you sure you've updated every bit? `this.state.potions` instead of `this.potions` everywhere. Set up the state in the constructor. What is the error?

Comment: Yes just updated it. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.potions.map is not a function`. Apparently, it's still not getting assigned.

Comment: I see. `potions` is an object, right? Could you post what the data looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the case when the data is empty

```
render() {
    const { potions, className } = this.state;

    if (!potions) {
      return (<p>Loading...</p>);
    } else {
      return (
          <div className="{className}">
              <ul>
                  {potions.map(potion => <li key={potion.id}>{potion.name}</li> )}
              </ul>
          </div>
      );
    }
}
```